# Synchronizing MultiSegmentAudioPlayers?

Tags: synchronization, open-source, audiokit

Is there a way to synchronize multiple MultiSegmentAudioPlayers to start playing exactly at the same time? In the API documentation there is no mention of such feature, all I  find is the `referenceTimeStamp` parameter to adjust the playback start position on the timeline. Can it be somehow used to achieve this kind of behavior?

When I looked at the code, MultiSegmentAudioPlayer allows public access to AVAudioPlayerNode inside it. Although when I directly call `playerNode.play(at: AVAudioTime?)` after `scheduleSegments(audioSegments:referenceTimeStamp:)` using the same AVAudioTime value for all of the players, the result is just something weird.

If this is not possible at the time and it's already recognized, but not just yet implemented, is it possible to participate implementing the feature? Is there a public backlog of upcoming features for AudioKit somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You need to schedule the start time of each MultiSegmentAudioPlayer's AVAudioPlayerNode correctly. Each needs to refer to the same concrete start time (derived from one of the players) + a delay to allow for processing. The following code snippet worked for me:

```
let players: [MultiSegmentAudioPlayer] = [...]
let segments: [MockSegment] = [...]

for (player, segment) in zip(players, segments) {
   player.scheduleSegments(audioSegments: [segment], referenceTimeStamp: 0)
}

let startDelayTime = 0.25
let now = players[0].playerNode.lastRenderTime!.sampleTime;
let sampleRate = Double(Settings.sampleRate)
let sampleTime = AVAudioFramePosition(Double(now) + (startDelayTime * sampleRate))
let startTime = AVAudioTime(sampleTime: sampleTime, atRate: sampleRate)

for player in players {
    player.playerNode.play(at: startTime)
}
```